# Upgrade to symfony 3 causes issues with whiteoctoberTCPDF

Tags: symfony-3.1

[error from composer update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iUDGK.png)

hi I am trying to upgrade to symfony 3.0.* and when I ran " composer update " command I have this error concerning  whiteoctober/tcpdf-bundle bundle :

> Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap
>   Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache
>   PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel' not found in /var/www/html/dlup/app/AppKernel.php on line 6
>   Script Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache handling the post-update-cmd event terminated with an exception

```
[RuntimeException]                                                                                                         
An error occurred when executing the "'cache:clear --no-warmup'" command:                                                  
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel' not found in /var/www/html/dlup/app/AppKernel.php on line 6
```

Comment: i will appreciate instead of voting -1 on question to have propositions . After all we are all here to learn more and to gain from each others

Answer (score 1):

to solve my problem .
first i autoload the kernel by adding in my composer.json file

```
"autoload": {
        "files":    [ "app/AppKernel.php" ]
    },
```

then i modify the file app/console.php
by adding on the top :

require_once **DIR**.'/autoload.php';

and i comment the line

```
//require_once __DIR__.'/AppKernel.php';
```

for more information go to https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/issues/868

after i delete the bundle whiteoctober/tcpdf-bundle manually .
the i look for a version compatible with symfony 3.3.2 which is the symfony 's version i am using . I add this require in my composer.json file

"require": {
"whiteoctober/tcpdf-bundle": "~the_Compatible_version_for_you"
    },

for me i did

```
    "require": {
"whiteoctober/tcpdf-bundle": "dev-master"
    },
```